# KendoUI Grid assigning options

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

im attempting to use KendoUI Grid for a piece of my project. The data source that I want to bind to the grid has a lot of extra pieces that i dont want as columns plus several other options. I was wondering if there is a way that I can set the options for the grid from javascript, but I seem to have a problem with the 'data' option when i try.

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: $parent.kendoGrid"></div>


....
program = ko.observable(null),
kendoGrid = { data: program.BettingInterest, sortable: true, columnMenu: true,
            columns: [{ field: 'BettingInterestProgramNumber', title: 'Post' }, 
                { field: 'PostPosition', title: 'PP' }, { field: 'MLOdd', title: 'ML' },
                { field: 'FractionalOdd', title: 'Odds' }, 'Jockey', 'Trainer', 'Owner', 
                { field: 'WeightCarried', title: 'Weight' }, { field: 'Medication', title: 'Med' },
                { field: 'ClaimingPrice', title: 'Claiming' }, 'Breed'], 
            scrollable: false, resizable: true
        },
....
```

'program' gets filled after the last in a series of Cascading Drop Downs
My grid shows with the columns and such but no actual data. I'm wondering if i'm just missing something simple...

Comment: Can you show how `program` gets filled? I'm not sure if you can bind the grid to `program.BettingInterest` when that property doesn't exist on the `program` observable. Also, you might want to try calling `.refresh()` on the grid after you populate `program`. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work property with the binding, you would need to create a computed that represents the current program's BettingInterest, so that it can track dependencies properly.  Your view model would look something like:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.program = ko.observable();
    this.programBettingInterest = ko.computed(function() {
       var program = this.program();
        return program ? program.BettingInterest : [];        
    }, this);

    this.myGrid = { data: this.programBettingInterest, sortable: true, columnMenu: true,
        columns: [{ field: 'propA', title: 'propertyA' }, 
            { field: 'propB', title: 'propertyB' }], 
        scrollable: false, resizable: true
    };
};
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/eqVWs/

Comment: Great! I feel silly for not thinking of that since I had something similar when I wasn't using KendoUI.